# download a youtube file as mp3 as bytes and save it to s3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, youtube-dl

Currently using a python package called youtube-dl to download a mp3 file and saving it locally. I want to download mp3 as  byes in memory and pass it to s3 bucket via BOTO instead of saving it locally first.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl


ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the download stream straight into an s3 object using boto3 buckets .put_object(Body=(the stream you're downloading)) - though there is a size limit on adding items to S3, which means multi part uploads which this may not support

Comment: How do i get the stream from youtube-dl?

Comment: That I have no idea. You'd have to see if they have an API but... they are quite jealous of their content so I sincerely doubt they do.